# When creating a new object and calling a method show error __init__() takes exactly 6 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, class

Actually when I call `display()` method through `obj2` it should show me `NULL` values. Expected output should be `Details Null Null Null Null Null`
. How should I do that ?

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self, fname, mname, lname, age, gender):
        self.fname = fname
        self.mname = mname
        self.lname = lname
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender
    def display(self):
        print "Details", self.fname, self.mname, self.lname, self.age, self.gender

obj1 = Human('John','W','Cooper',23,'Male')
obj1.display()
obj2 = Human()
obj2.display()
```

Comment: Indentation is broken in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify default values for the arguments of your constructors.

So, what you would want to do is something like this:

`def __init__(self, fname=None, mname=None, lname=None, age=None, gender=None):`

Also, note that python uses `None`, not `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

`obj2 = Human()`

Here you're making an instance which expects 6 arguments (Python adds one), but you only add one (the one which Python adds).

If you want it so if you add nothing, the parameters are `None`, you should do:

```
def __init__(self, fname=None, mname=None, lname=None, age=None, gender=None):
```

This will make all the parameters be `None` unless stated otherwise.